# Strange behaviour of ld output with '-print-memory-usage'

Tags: gcc, linker, size, ld

I am trying to get %-age of using RAM and FLASH memory sections for microcontroller.
Here is the [linker file](https://github.com/sadkotheguest/ch32v307-cmake-vsc-noos-template/blob/main/wch/Ld/Link.ld).

(toolchain: xPack for RISC-V, GCC-12.2)
When I'm using the first notation:

```
    .stack ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM) - __stack_size :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        PROVIDE(_susrstack = . );
        . = . + __stack_size;
        PROVIDE( _eusrstack = .);
    } >RAM
```

I've got 100% usage of RAM.

When I'm using the next one notation:

```
    .stack :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        PROVIDE(_susrstack = . );
        . = . + __stack_size;
        PROVIDE( _eusrstack = .);
    } >RAM
```

I've got 3% of RAM usage.

But in fact I've just moving the stack inside the section.

---

When I'm using old one GCC 8.3 - everything is OK in both cases.

I've compared the output of *ld* with *'-print-memory-usage'* for GCC 12.2 and 8.3.
The behaviour differs.

Are there any ways to ignore the .stack and .heap sections during %-age of used memory  calculation? –

Answer (score 2):

The new LD behavior sounds correct as all RAM is being used.

If you wish to exclude a stack segment from the memory usage count, simply create a separate memory zone for it.

```
...
        RAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K - __stack_size
        STACK (rw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000 - __stack_size, LENGTH = __stack_size
...
        .stack : {
            . = ALIGN(4);
            PROVIDE(_susrstack = . );
            . = . + __stack_size;
            PROVIDE( _eusrstack = .);
        } >STACK
...
```

Voila:

```
Memory region         Used Size  Region Size  %age Used
           FLASH:        4520 B       256 KB      1.72%
             RAM:          56 B        62 KB      0.09%
           STACK:          2 KB         2 KB    100.00%
```

simple and graceful, isn't it?